# I get the error ERROR Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out what's wrong with this query:

```
SELECT 
    user_master.user_id,
    user_master.business_id,
    user_master.user_name,
    user_master.lastname,
    user_master.user_type_id,
    user_master.group_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(group_master.group_name) GroupName
FROM
    user_master
        JOIN
    group_master ON FIND_IN_SET(group_master.group_id,
            user_master.group_id)
        JOIN
    group_master ON group_master.group_id = user_master.group_id AND group_master.business_id = user_master.business_id
WHERE
    user_type_id = '3' AND user_master.business_id = '248' AND user_master.email_id <> '' AND user_master.user_name <> 'Test' AND user_master.lastname <> 'Learner' AND user_master.is_deleted = '0' AND user_master.is_active = '1'
GROUP BY user_master.user_id
order by user_master.user_name ASC
```

Upon execution I get the error `ERROR Not unique table/alias`.

Comment: Why do you join *group_master* with *user_master* twice?

Answer (score 0):

You are joining `group_master` twice, so you need to put different name for each of them, In your case you have two relation with same name which is invalid. Define different aliases for them in order to make them unique in your query.